# A weird looking inequality in Algebra by Serge Lang

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I recently came across this bizarre question in Algebra by Lang:

> 16. Let $w$ be  a complex number, and let $c = \max(1, |w|)$.
>       Let $F, G$ be non-zero polynomials in one variable with complex coefficients, of degrees $d$ and $d'$ respectively, such that $|F|, |G| \geq 1$.
>       Let $R$ be their resultant.
>       Then
>       $$
>            |R|
>       \leq c^{d+d'} [|F(w)| + |G(w)|] |F|^{d'} |G|^d (d + d')^{d + d'}.
>     $$
>       (We denote by $|F|$ the maximum of the absolute values of the coefficients of $F$.)
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7CQP.png)

Can anyone provide me with any hints? Any help will be appreciated.